# Winmount.sys driver BSOD

Tags: windows-7

On a Windows 7 machine I downloaded Microsoft's Virtual CD-Rom  Control Panel: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38780 to mount an iso. I've never used this before, and couldn't remember what I have used in the past. When you download this tool, you extract it. There is a driver, the executable, and a read me file. As per the readme, I moved the driver to the system32/drivers directory. When I started the executable, it directs you to point to the driver. I accidentally clicked and started the Winmount.sys driver. Immediately Windows crashed and the bsod came up. Any ideas?

Comment: use a different tool like http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

Comment: I understand there are many other tools to chose from, I am looking for  what to do to recover Windows. I thought about removing the program in safe mode, or stopping in device manager, but I can only get a command prompt open

Comment: delete the .SYS file and look if this stops Windows from doing a BSOD

Comment: Isn't that driver nescessary for Windows?

Comment: I have a Windows VM and I did the same thing to test, and this does not work.

Comment: I mean the driver that is part of the download and which you copied before. Winmount.sys sounds like a different 3rd party tool: http://www.winmount.com/ which conflicts with the MS tool.

Comment: I spelled it wrong, sorry wimmount.sys, Windows images. The problem came from starting that sys file from the iso tool. The driver that is part of the download was never started, so there is not a conflict

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, in safe mode I opened VCdControlTool.exe and in Driver Control removed the driver. Was able to boot fine after that.

Comment: Can you identify where 'VCdControlTool.exe' is and provide a bit more data?

Comment: This is the right fix, if you have problems with booting to safe mode from the automatic recovery screen. Try explicitly hitting F8 and launching safe mode from there. As to the location of VCdControlTool.exe it will vary it should be the same place you originally extracted the .sys driver file.